# RevenueCat - One subscription to different users

Tags: android, flutter, store, subscription, revenuecat

When I subscribe with a user, which is the same email as the cell phone account, then I logout and then I login with another user, this new user appears to me as having a subscription when it doesn't, it's like the subscription of the first user also happens to this new one.